# Java.net.ConnectException: Keycloak's Client gets Connection refused on Docker while Auth routing

Tags: spring, docker, spring-security, keycloak, connectionexception

**If I have a Keycloak server running in local docker desktop and a client application running locally (non dockerized scenario), It works fine.**

If I have Keycloak server and a client application running in local docker desktop, It throws

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
        ... 64 more
```

If I run my client application in a local (non-dockerized) environment and pointing to a dockerized keycloak server of the cloud instance, I get the following error.

```
2022-02-18 12:59:55.039  WARN 1192 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Failed to load URLs from http://XXXX.CLOUD.XXXX:8180/auth/realms/SampleKeycloakApp/.well-known/openid-configuration


java.lang.Exception: Forbidden
        at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getOidcConfiguration(KeycloakDeployment.java:233) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.1.jar!/:16.1.1]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.resolveUrls(KeycloakDeployment.java:182) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.1.jar!/:16.1.1]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getAuthUrl(KeycloakDeployment.java:251) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.1.jar!/:16.1.1]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.getRedirectUri(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:175) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.1.jar!/:16.1.1]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.loginRedirect(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:213) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.1.jar!/:16.1.1]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:275) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.1.jar!/:16.1.1]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:138) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.1.jar!/:16.1.1]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:154) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-16.1.1.jar!/:16.1.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-16.1.1.jar!/:16.1.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Sharing the docker-compose file for reference here when I run the both services in docker.

```
version: "3"

services:   springboot:
    build: .
    container_name: springboot
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
      - keycloak
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/todolist
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_URI: https://keycloak:8443/auth
      REALM: SpringBootKeycloakApp
    networks:
      - common-network    keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:14.0.0
    container_name: keycloak
    ports:
      - "8180:8180"
      - "8443:8443"
    command: ["-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100"]
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - common-network   db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todolist
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - common-network   postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - common-network networks:   common-network:
    driver: bridge 
    volumes:   
      db-data:
        driver: local   
      postgres_data:
        driver: local
```

and when I run the client app separately in non-docker env, I run it with `java -jar ClientApp.jar`

and when I run the client app separately in docker env, I use the following Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
ARG JAR_FILE=./build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} ClientApp.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "ClientApp.jar"]
```

I would be happy to understand the real root cause behind this and run the keycloak server and the client application in a dockerized cloud instance without any issues. Thx.

Comment: Could you please provide command which you are using to start docker app and keycloak? Connection refused problem in most cases means that nothing listen on the port, so there is no connection between your app and keycloak. There are two possible ways to resolve this: make network mode: host, or use default approach and use bridge mode(that is default one), but container can reach each other by their container names. With more details it would be easier to figure out the problem.

Comment: @DariyN - Updated the docker files that I use to run both.

Comment: Everything looks good from dockerfile/docker-compose perspective. I have only one assumption here: depends_on does not wait until container application inside completely start, so I think that your application starts faster then keycloak, that's why you're getting this error. Let's try to start keycloak and application separately, from different docker-compose files.

Comment: no, @DariyN! I still have my DockerFile, don't I? So I tried my luck by separating the app in a DockerFile (showed above) from the docker-compose file and checked accessing them both too. the result is no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use both keycloak server and the client in Cloud, use ssl-required=none

```
  keycloak.ssl-required=none
```

If you use both keycloak server and the client in localhost, use ssl-required=external

```
keycloak.ssl-required=external
```

Comment: what if one's on the cloud and one is local, more specifically, spring app is in local.

Comment: @PrasannjeetSingh - Pl read my question's first line and you might find the answer.

Comment: No, I didn't find the answer by reading your question's first line. But thanks for your help anyways :)